# oh-my-zsh installation returns non zero code

Tags: docker, oh-my-zsh

I'm trying to install oh-my-zsh as part of a Docker build (using a Dockerfile). Here's the dockerfile line in question:

```
RUN wget https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/raw/master/tools/install.sh -O - | zsh`
```

and the error I get is:

> The command [/bin/sh -c wget https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/raw/master/tools/install.sh -O - | zsh] returned a non-zero code: 1

[Full error gist here](https://gist.github.com/tal-moshayov/e4d05914f861eba7fbd7)

To debug, I've run the command manually and it works. Did anyone have luck installing oh-my-zsh as part of a docker build? any idea why it behaves differently if run this way?

Comment: have a look at the 32 containers for zsh on the Hub https://registry.hub.docker.com/search?q=zsh&searchfield=

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Build failing because install.sh return non zero code, when you execute script manually you are ignoring return code, but docker failing build. Usually non-zero return code indicate error, but if in this case everything ok you could ignore this error:

```
RUN wget https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/raw/master/tools/install.sh -O - | zsh || true
```

Comment: right. it seems that everything is installed just fine, but error code 1 is returned. so I'm adopting this force-true approach. thx.